# C++ binary max heap Read Access Violation

Tags: c++, exception, heap, binary-tree

So I'm making a binary max heap for my c++ class and I keep encountering this exception saying that I'm returning a nullptr in my class methods. I'm having trouble finding where it could be at in my code so any help would be greatly appreciated. The exception that keeps getting thrown is as follows:

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > ::_Get_data**(...) returned nullptr. occurred
```

Here's my header file for the tree:
        #ifndef HEAP_H
        #define HEAP_H

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "THeapNode.h"

    class TreeHeap {
    private:
        THeapNode *root;  // the top node of the heap

        int next_loc;   // the next valid location to place a node

        void bubble_up(THeapNode *node);    //performs the bubble up operation on the given node

        void bubble_down(THeapNode *node);  //performs the bubble down operation on the given node

        void clear_heap(THeapNode *node); // removes all elements from the heap




    public:

        TreeHeap();    // the constructor

        ~TreeHeap();   // the destructor

        THeapNode* find_node(const int position);   // finds the node in the position given and returns a pointer to it

        void insert(const string &item);    // creates a node with the string given as the value and places it in the next location

        bool Delete();  // removes the root of the heap and returns false if the tree is empty
    };

    #endif
```

Here's my Node's .h file:

```
    #ifndef NODE_H
    #define NODE_H
    #include<string>
    using std::string;

    struct THeapNode {
        string data;    // stores a data string
        THeapNode *parent;  // a pointer to the parent node
        THeapNode *rightChild;     // a pointer to the right child node
        THeapNode *leftChild;   // a pointer to the left child node
        THeapNode( const string &str );
    };

    #endif
```

And here's my .cpp file:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <cmath>
    #include "TreeHeap.h"
    #include "THeapNode.h"


    TreeHeap::TreeHeap() {
        root = NULL;   
        next_loc = 1;
    };

    TreeHeap::~TreeHeap() {

        THeapNode *current = root;
        THeapNode *deleteNode = NULL;
        int d = floor(log2(next_loc - 1));
        int j = next_loc;

        for ( int i = 1; i <= j-1; i++ ) {

            while (1) {

                int d = floor(log2(next_loc - i));
                int power = std::pow(2, d - 1);

                if (next_loc == 1) {
                    deleteNode = current;
                    j -= 1;
                }
                else if (next_loc < (std::pow(2, d - 1) * 3)) {
                    current = current->leftChild;
                }
                else {
                    current = current->rightChild;
                }

                // Update location and depth to reflect traversal
                next_loc = std::pow(2, d - 1) + next_loc % power;
                d = d - 1;
            }

            clear_heap(deleteNode);

        }

    }

    void TreeHeap::clear_heap(THeapNode *node) {

        if (node == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        node->data = "";
        node->leftChild = NULL;
        node->rightChild = NULL;
        node->parent = NULL;

    }

    void TreeHeap::insert( const string &value ) {

        THeapNode newNode = THeapNode(value);
        int loc = next_loc;

        if (loc == 1) {
            *root = newNode;
        }

        THeapNode *current = root;

        while (1) {

            int d = floor(log2(loc));
            int power = std::pow(2, d - 1);

            if (loc < (power * 3)) {
                if (current->leftChild = nullptr) {
                    *current->leftChild = newNode;
                    newNode.parent = current;
                    next_loc += 1;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    current = current->leftChild;
                }
            }

            else {
                if (current->rightChild = nullptr) {
                    *current->rightChild = newNode;
                    newNode.parent = current;
                    next_loc = +1;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    current = current->rightChild;
                }
            }

            // Update location and depth to reflect traversal
            loc = std::pow(2, d - 1) + loc % power;
            d = d - 1;

        }
        std::cout << current->data << "\n";
        system("PAUSE");

    }

    void TreeHeap::bubble_up( THeapNode *node ) {

        if (node == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        THeapNode *parent = node->parent;

        while ( parent->data < node->data ) {
            parent = node->parent;
            string temp = parent->data;
            parent->data = node->data;
            node->data = temp;
            }

    }

    void TreeHeap::bubble_down( THeapNode *node ) {

        if (node == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        while( node->data < node->rightChild->data || node->data < node->leftChild->data ){
            if (node->rightChild->data > node->leftChild->data) {

                THeapNode *right = node->rightChild;
                string temp = right->data;
                right->data = node->data;
                node->data = temp;
            }
            else if (node->rightChild->data < node->leftChild->data) {

                THeapNode *left = node->leftChild;
                string temp = left->data;
                left->data = node->data;
                node->data = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    THeapNode* TreeHeap::find_node( const int position ){

        int loc = position;
        int d = floor(log2(position));
        int power = std::pow(2, d - 1);
        THeapNode *returnValue = root;

        while (returnValue != NULL && 1 < position && position < (next_loc - 1)) {

            if (loc == 1) {
                return returnValue;
            }
            else if (loc < ( std::pow( 2, d-1 ) * 3)) {
                returnValue = returnValue->leftChild;
            }
            else {
                returnValue = returnValue->rightChild;
            }

            // Update location and depth to reflect traversal
            loc = std::pow(2, d - 1) + loc % power;
            d = d - 1;
        }
        std::cout << returnValue->data<<"\n";
        return returnValue;
    }

    bool TreeHeap::Delete() {

        if (next_loc = 1) {
            return false;
        }

        int d = floor(log2(next_loc - 1));
        THeapNode *current = root;
        THeapNode *usedNode = NULL;
        int loc = next_loc - 1;

        while ( 1 ) {

            int d = floor(log2(loc));
            int power = std::pow(2, d - 1);

            if (loc == 1) {
                usedNode = current;
                break;
            }
            else if (loc < (std::pow(2, d - 1) * 3)) {
                current = current->leftChild;
            }
            else {
                current = current->rightChild;
            }

            // Update location and depth to reflect traversal
            loc = std::pow(2, d - 1) + loc % power;
            d = d - 1;
        }



        THeapNode *temp = root;
        clear_heap(root);
        root = usedNode;
        delete temp;

        bubble_down(root);

        return true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you've got.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I've gone through it somewhat but I'm not exactly proficient with the visual studio debugger

Comment: does not compile

Comment: No, it doesn't compile

Comment: @Conrad2098 You need to get proficient with it. But this is simple. Set some break points where you think the error might be. And run your code. Then use "step over" to step through your code line by line until it eventually throws the error then you know WHERE it happened and then can figure out WHY.

Comment: @Conrad2098 And you need to provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help!

Comment: And I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: Why in the world are you implementing a binary heap as a tree? Binary heap is more easily implemented in an array. If you need a node (i.e. tree-based) heap, then you'd be better off with something like Pairing heap.

Comment: Oh, and I'll echo the comment about learning to use the debugger. It'll take you maybe an hour, and it'll save you more than that the next time you run into a bug in your code (i.e. tomorrow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick inspection reveals errors in your `bubble_up` and `bubble_down` functions.

In `bubble_up`, you have the following:

```
    THeapNode *parent = node->parent;

    while ( parent->data < node->data ) {
        parent = node->parent;
        string temp = parent->data;
        parent->data = node->data;
        node->data = temp;
        }
```

This is going to fail when a node bubbles all the way to the top, because it doesn't check for the node being at the root. You need to write:

```
while (parent != NULL && parent->data < node->data)
```

In `bubble_down`, you have this code:

```
    while( node->data < node->rightChild->data || node->data < node->leftChild->data ){
        if (node->rightChild->data > node->leftChild->data) {
```

You don't check to see if the `rightChild` or `leftChild` are NULL.

More importantly, that looks like an infinite loop to me because you never change the value of `node`.

Those are just the errors I saw on a quick read through your code. There might be more.